# How to manipulate count based on sub-values in TWIG?

Tags: twig, conditional-statements

I was wondering how to manipulate / render the count based on sub-rules.
In the current situation specifications are counted and when there are more than 5, a link is shown to show more specifications. I wanted to show only specs that have a value like this:

```
{% for spec in product.specs | limit(5) %}
   {% if spec.value %}
      <li>
         <span>{{ spec.title }}</span>
         {{ spec.value }}
     </li>
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% if product.specs | length > 5 %}
   <li class="more"><a href="./">{{ 'View all specifications' | t }}</a></li>
{% endif %}
```

In this case the count is done before checking the values of the sub-items, so the "Show more" link is visible and clickable, but doesn't show more specifications, because they are stripped out, because the value is empty but is counted as item.

The goal is to hide the "Show more" link when there are < 5 items WITH values.

I hope anyone could point me in the right direction :-)

Thank you very much for thinking with me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either use an extra counter to count the valid elements,

```html
{% for spec in product.specs  | limit(5) %}
   {% if spec.value %}
      <li>
         <span>{{ spec.title }}</span>
         {{ spec.value }}
     </li>
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% set cnt = 0 %}
{% for spec in product.specs %}
    {% if spec.value %}{% set cnt = cnt + 1 %}{% endif %}
{% endfor %}


{% if cnt >= 5 %}
   <li class="more"><a href="./">{{ 'View all specifications' }}</a></li>
{% endif %}
```

Or you can use the filter `filter`

```html
{% if products.specs| filter(spec => spec.value|default) | length >= 5 %}
   <li class="more"><a href="./">{{ 'View all specifications' }}</a></li>
{% endif %}
```

---

Update as for your comment (and as you don't have access to `filter`)
You can't just limit the result before hand. So in the first part you would also need to use a counter

```
{% set cnt = 0 %}
{% for spec in product.specs %}
    {% if cnt < 5 %}
        {% if spec.value %}
        <li>
            <span>{{ spec.title }}</span>
            {{ spec.value }}
        </li>
        {% set cnt = cnt + 1 %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Great solution @DarkBee! But .. I'm almost there, but not completely. The filter method didn't work for me as 'filter' isn't implemented as it seems. (We're using Lightspeed HQ). The first solution will work, BUT there's a catch... When it starts counting, which is after the limit, it counts also the empty specs. Let's say that it start its looping-thing and there are 2 specs without a value, it just hides that ones. Ending up with 3 specs and a 'Show more' link, instead of 5. I must say that I really like your approach!

Comment: It shouldn't count the empty specs as before I increment the counter I test the value with `{% if spec.value %}`?

Comment: I absolutely agree with you! I really do, but this is the only explanation I have for the results. Please check it out: this one gives you five specs:
https://www.sceneryworkshop.nl/model-color-white-17ml-70951-1923975.html#section-specifications

And this one 4:
https://www.sceneryworkshop.nl/model-color-orange-fluo-17ml-70733.html#section-specifications

Comment: See my update, also maybe consider filtering the spec before sending them to the template

Comment: I used your updated code and it works great! Thanks for all of your help @DarkBee!